# What is the impact of intermittent traceroute timeouts

Tags: network-monitoring, networking

There are intermittent timeouts upon doing traceroute to an IP address. What impact does it have on say when you are trying to connect to a DB from an App server?

```
traceroute to <IP>(<IP>), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * <dns name> (<IP>)  0.144 ms  0.096 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little to none. Traceroute is a tool for determining the path from one host to another, it is not a tool for analyzing the quality of that path. See my answer to this question as to why:

[Intermittent high ping/latency problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/286588/intermittent-high-ping-latency-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Traceroute timeouts *may* be indicitave of connectivity issues, but they can not confirm issues, as devices along the path may be configured to drop ICMP packets.